# D-Link 150 Mbps N150 Wireless ADSL2+ Router wifi not working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip

I bought `D-Link N150 Wireless ADSL2+ Router` one year ago. I got a broadband  connection from MTNL http://mtnldelhi.in/, and used wifi and ethernet connection. There was a guy from MTNL office, who did the rest of the work.

Now, I am in my college. Our university got a private address in the range of `10.x.y.z`. I live in my hostel. The IP allocation in the hostel is done manually. Earlier I had a TPLink router. I used to manually set the IP of this router, and got wifi connections easily.

The problem is with my new `D-Link N150 Wireless ADSL2+ Router`. I don't have to set anything in the router. No IP setup nothing. The ethernet connection works fine if I set the IP of the devices connected via it. But, I am unable to use wifi connection in the router.

What I have tried till now:

1. Set the IP of router manually, it doesn't make any difference.
2. Set the IP of the mobile device manually, it doesn't work either.
3. Tried to manually put the IP in the range like `192.168.x.x`, but it didn't work either.

How can I solve this. Please help me to solve this.

Edit : My router is not working. It means that I am getting wifi connection. My mobile is connected to wifi, but no network access.

My router related info is: http://www.dlinkmea.com/partner/media/product_item_downloadables/8641-DSL-2730U_Datasheet_01(HQ).pdf

Comment: Your problem description isn't very helpful. It just says that that you are "unable to use" the connection. Well, why? What goes wrong when you try? (Putting the mobile devices manually into an IP range that isn't valid for your network is not going to work.)

Comment: I don't understand the problem very well but if you have to manually set the devices ip address to work it looks like a DHCP problem. Check if the router DHCP server is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work with the default firmware. It expects "the internet"(WAN) to come over a phone line, yours is ethernet. Some ADSL modems support this too, yours doesnt. What you want is a "Cable router".

Alternatively DDWRT/OpenWRT may solve this, but based on your question you may find that quite difficult to setup.

Comment: But, ethernet is working fine. Only router is causing problem.

Comment: @learner: Well duh. You cannot use an ADSL router with a non-ADSL connection. Not to mention if you do it wrong you'll screw up the campus network and get booted off pretty quick.